# Handling type information gracefully

Tags: haskell

I've been impressed by haskell and its claims that it could avoid problems like the kind that crashed the mars orbiter (due to differences between conventions in two programs, miles vs kms: [source](http://www.cnn.com/TECH/space/9909/30/mars.metric.02/)), by catching them at compile time.  Though I can't recollect where I read about this anymore.

I assume the original program was of the form (in some other language):

```
speed :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
speed distance time = distance * 1.0 / time
```

I tried writing a variant that would gracefully handle this bug in haskell (ignore division by zero for now):

```
data Dist a = KM a | Miles a deriving (Show)

speed' :: Fractional a => Dist a -> a -> a
speed' (KM dist) time = dist * 1.0 / time
speed' (Miles dist) time = dist * 1.6 / time
```

Now it still isn't obvious that the return type of speed' is KM/second

Now I'm trying to answer the question; What would a nice haskell implementation that made the return type more obvious look like:

So for I've attempted to write a few data types (and I've probably gone down the wrong path?).

```
data Distance a = Meter a | Inch a | Furlong a |  LightYear a | Fathom a deriving (Show)

data Time a = Second a | Hour a | Minute a | Year a deriving (Show)
```

[You can imagine many more values for Distance and Time ]

For each of these data types we can implement the necessary conversions so you may perform operations on each of these types as follows:

```
instance Num a => Num (Time a) where
  Second a + Second b = Second (a+b)
  Minute a + Minute b = Minute (a+b)
  Minute a + Second b = Second (a*60 + b)
  Second a + Minute b = Second ( a + b*60)
  Second a - Second b = Second (a-b)
  Minute a - Minute b = Minute (a-b)
  Minute a - Second b = Second (a*60 - b)
  Second a - Minute b = Second ( a - b*60)
  abs (Second a) = Second (abs a)
  abs (Minute a) = Minute (abs a)
  signum (Second a) = Second (signum a)
  signum (Minute a) = Minute (signum a)
  fromInteger a = Second (fromInteger a)
-- I'm clearly not thinking along the right 'haskelly' lines for these :/
-- These are to deal with concepts like acceleration distance/time squared
--  Second a * Second b  = Second (Second (a*b)
--  Second a * Minute b  = Second (Second (a*b*60))
--  Minute a * Second b  = Second (Second (a*b*60))
--  Minute a * Num b     = Minute (a*b)
--  Second a * Num b     = Second (a*b)
```

[similarly for all conversions for Distance]

At this point I'm lost on how I would implement speed in a reasonable manner using these new data types such that they may be operated upon [say for addition].

Comment: Perhaps you can draw some inspiration from the [units](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/units) and [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) packages.

Comment: first: I know that this is probably not helping you - but if you are mainly interested in this stuff (and not Haskell) than maybe a look at F# is worth your time - it is a reasonable good FP language and is has [units of measure](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/units-of-measure/) which is exactly what you are trying to do here

Comment: Check out Adam Gundry's type checker plugin for this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uom-plugin

Comment: These are some excellent links. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

In your proposed `speed'`, indeed it is no clearer what units the result has. You can't just take in a `Distance a` and return an `a`, because then the unit information is gone. Instead you need something like

```
data DistanceUnit = Mile | Kilometer
data TimeUnit = Second | Hour

data Dist a = Dist a DistanceUnit
data Time a = Time a TimeUnit

speed'' :: Fractional a => Dist a -> Time a -> Dist (Time a)
speed'' (Dist d dUnit) (Time t tUnit) = Dist (Time (d / t) tUnit) dUnit

inMiles :: Fractional a => Dist a -> a
inMiles (Dist d Mile) = d
inMiles (Dist d Kilometer) = d / 1.6

inHours :: Fractional a => Time a -> a
-- same pattern as above

inMph :: Fractional a => Dist (Time a) -> a
inMph (Dist (Time s tUnit) dUnit) = inMiles (Dist s dUnit) / inHours (Time s tUnit)

thrusterAmount :: Fractional a => Dist (Time a) -> Int
thrusterAmount dv = inMph dv / 2 -- rocket science goes here

goFaster :: Fractional a => Dist (Time a) -> IO ()
goFaster dv = applyThrusters . thrusterAmount $ dv
```

This example I threw together is quite primitive and cobbled together, but I hope you can see the idea: keep the units around and write functions like `speed` in terms of generic "distance expressed somehow, divided by time expressed somehow". Then, when you really need to know a magnitude in order to do something external to the system, like fire the thrusters, you convert the dimensional quantity into a bare number, implicitly in whatever units are convenient for you.

A more sophisticated units system than mine would have better ways to express compound units like m/s or m^2s, but at any rate each function has its dimensions (but not its units!) encoded into its type: `speed` takes a distance and a time, and returns a distance per time, `distanceTraveled` might take a starting speed, an acceleration, and a time; and return a distance. There's no chance to misinterpret any of these things except at the very boundaries to the system, where you can call `inMph dv` and then immediately treat it as if it were kph, but the proximity to the `inMph` call should make such errors pretty obvious.